# 10 seconds install scripts makes a personal install, why?

Tags: gnu-parallel

I'm running the 10 seconds install with

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/) | bash
```

but for some reason, it does a personal install. I'm running it in docker with the williamyeh/ansible:ubuntu14.04 image (requires running apt update -qq && apt install curl -yq beforehand).

This is problematic because /root/bin isn't in the path.

Why can't the script make a full install and resorts to a personal install at /root/bin?

Answer (score 1):

You'll also need `make` to be on the system:

```
apt update -qq && apt install curl make -yq
```

If you don't have make it will enter the `else` branch on line 93 which will cause it to copy the files directly to /root/bin.

> This is problematic because /root/bin isn't in the path.

The install script adds it to PATH anyway, so if you want it to work with a local install, you just need to start a new session or run `source ~/.bashrc` after installing.